# Spring Boot - Access JPA entity properties in controller method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having difficulty accessing the data of an instance JPA entity in my Spring Boot controller.

These are the entities:

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique=true, length=50)
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Authority:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Authority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String authority;
}
```

**UserRepository:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

This is the controller method:

```
@RestController
public class InfoController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/userinfo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public Optional<User> getUser() {
        Optional<User> foundUser = repository.findByUsername("testuser");

        return foundUser;
    }
}
```

When I access */userinfo* in my browser I get this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "testuser",
    "password": "",
    "enabled": true,
    "authorities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "authority": "ADMIN"
        }
    ]
}
```

So that's ok, looking good so far, but what I want to do is iterate over the *authorities* property of the User object in the controller, but I can't seem to access it (or any other property).  I've tried using methods such as:

```
foundUser.getAuthorities();

foundUser.authorities;

foundUser.get('authorities');
```

....But none of those methods exist.  How do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `foundUser` is an `Optional<User>` and not a `User`, so you cannot call methods of class `User` on it.

You'll have to get the `User` out of the `Optional` in order to access its attributes:

```
if (foundUser.isPresent()) {
    User user = foundUser.get();
    List<Authority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();
    // Do what you need to do with the list of authorities
}
```

You can also use the functional programming style of working, by using the methods that are available on class `Optional` such as `map`. For example, if you would want to get just the name of the user in an `Optional` when it is found, you could do this:

```
// Transforms the Optional<User> to an Optional<String> containing the username
Optional<String> username = foundUser.map(User::getUsername);
```

Or a list of the authorities in an `Optional`:

```
Optional<List<Authority>> authorities = foundUser.map(User::getAuthorities);
```

`Optional` represents an object that either contains a value or nothing. Your repository will return an `Optional` containing a `User` object when the user was found, or an empty `Optional` if the user was not found.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling methods on the `Optional` object, not the actual `User` object.

You can retrieve the `User` object by calling `User actualUser = foundUser.get()` .

Note that the call to `Optional.get()` throws `NoSuchElementException` if there is no value.